# How to control 3d printer printing in metal?

Tags: metal-printing

I have a question. Home printers are controlled via open-source software such as Pronterface. These printers print mostly in plastic, but how to control the "metal" printer. The principle of the printing here is a little different. Is it possible to use, for example, Pronterface for this task or the completely different software is needed?

Comment: Most metal printers run on proprietary software that comes with the printer. Since you haven't specified what specific printer you are trying to control, I'm voting to close this as "too broad".

Comment: Hi, Bartosz, and welcome to 3D Printer SE! I completely agree with Tom that your question is too broad in it's current state for you to get any useful answers. I will put it on hold until further edits. Also, I recommend you have a look at our [help section](http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help) for an introduction to Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pronterface would control the printer, but you would need a slicer that could give you g-code that works with said metal printer. Being it would be using metal, most of those are powder based, using a laser to sinter. The slicers for FDM based machines would not create the correct g-code for the application. I know there has been some effort around powder based printers (both metal and plastic) but I do not know of any software that has resulted from these efforts.

This wiki index for powder printers may be of some help to find out what software they are working on, most likely a custom solution.
http://reprap.org/wiki/Powder

Comment: You seem to be assuming that a metal 3D printer would take G-code at all or could be controlled over serial, which might not necessarily be true. It is better to only attempt to answer questions that are well-posed, and this one isn't (given that the specific printer isn't specified, the answer could be either "yes" or "no").